# Why does the heroku domain gives me a EADDRNOTAVAIL error?

Tags: node.js, http, heroku, server, json-server

I am trying to deploy a json-server db to heroku but i get the `address not available` error.

I use this command as the web dyno: `json-server -p $PORT --watch ./data/grades.json -H filex-grades.herokuapp.com`

The `json-server` does start but then it gives me a `EADDRNOTAVAIL` error. Here's the log:

```sh
2019-05-10T18:09:34.147439+00:00 app[web.1]: \{^_^}/ hi!
2019-05-10T18:09:34.147746+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-05-10T18:09:34.147982+00:00 app[web.1]: Loading ./data/grades.json
2019-05-10T18:09:34.169691+00:00 app[web.1]: Done
2019-05-10T18:09:34.188714+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-05-10T18:09:34.188850+00:00 app[web.1]: Resources
2019-05-10T18:09:34.188925+00:00 app[web.1]: http://filex-grades.herokuapp.com:33895/grades
2019-05-10T18:09:34.188994+00:00 app[web.1]: http://filex-grades.herokuapp.com:33895/external
2019-05-10T18:09:34.189055+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-05-10T18:09:34.189146+00:00 app[web.1]: Home
2019-05-10T18:09:34.189213+00:00 app[web.1]: http://filex-grades.herokuapp.com:33895
2019-05-10T18:09:34.189272+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-05-10T18:09:34.189710+00:00 app[web.1]: Type s + enter at any time to create a snapshot of the database
2019-05-10T18:09:34.191688+00:00 app[web.1]: Watching...
2019-05-10T18:09:34.191757+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228660+00:00 app[web.1]: Some error occurred { Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 52.5.226.222:33895
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228663+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1253:19)
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228665+00:00 app[web.1]: at listenInCluster (net.js:1318:12)
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228667+00:00 app[web.1]: at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1451:7)
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228668+00:00 app[web.1]: at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228670+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228672+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: 'EADDRNOTAVAIL',
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228673+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'listen',
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228675+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '52.5.226.222',
2019-05-10T18:09:34.228677+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 33895 }
```

I was thinking it may have something to do with Heroku redirecting from `http` to `https`

Comment: When I visit the address given by the logs it does send me to a Heroku site but it says nothing is built yet.

Comment: I couldn't find the reason I got the error, but in the end I got my app running by using json-server as a module.